# Regular subobject classifer is preserved by reflections?

Tags: category-theory

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a category with a regular subobject classifier (see Adamek - The Joy of Cats, for definitions) and $\mathcal{A}$ a full replete bireflective subcategory of $\mathcal{B}$, is it true that $\mathcal{A}$ has regular subobject classifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion functor of a full coreflective category is comonadic, i.e. realizes the subcategory as the coalgebras for the associated comonad. If the category is additionally reflective, then the comonad is exact. It's a general theorem (50.4 in Oswald Wyler's Lecture Notes on Topoi and Quasitopoi) that if partial morphisms with a certain codomain are represented, then so are partial morphisms of coalgebras with codomain the cofree coalgebra on that codomain. Since subobject classifiers represent partial morphisms with codomain a terminal object, and since the right adjoint preserves terminal objects, it follows that a full bireflective subcategory has a regular subobject classifier if the original category does.